# Как запустить код в VS Code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Взялся изучать `JS`, установил `VS Code`. Написал код, однако запустить его не могу. Нажимаю отладка, запуск без отладки, и выдается ошибка. Вопрос: как запустить код в `VS Code`?

Comment: Ошибка какая?..

Comment: @Dmitry Что то вроде этого [Running] node "c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\java.js"
"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

Comment: если не париться, то рядом положить файлик html и в нем подключить скрипт...запускаете html в браузере и скрипт работает. Или вы кроме скрипта js еще что-то юзаете?

Comment: можно ещё поставить расширение https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WallabyJs.quokka-vscode

но это так для не сложных вычислений

Answer (score 5):

В вопросе не указана ОС. Если Windows, то:

1. Установить Node.js
2. Установить расширение Code Runner для VS Code
3. Перезапустить VS Code
4. В VS Code в правом верхнем углу нажать запуск (Run Code) или Ctrl + Alt + N

В большинстве случаев никакие конфигурационные файлы править не нужно.

Также обратите внимание, что привычное для руководств `alert("Hello World");` работать не будет, попробуйте `console.log("Hello World");`

Answer (score 2):

Установить Node.js.
Создать файл file.js
Открыть терминал `Ctrl + ~`
Запустить команду `node file.js`.

P.S. По-умолчанию команда ищет файл **от корня папки (workspace)**, которая открыта в vscode.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тут есть несколько способов...

**1)** Скачиваете расширение *Debugger for Chrome* - должен появиться файл **launch.json**. Или он вместе с vs устанавливается, уже не помню... но он будет 100%.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Указываете **url** как на картинке(путь к файлу, который вы собираетесь запустить). Создаёте базовый **html** и вставляете туда скрипт.

**2)** Способ похож на предыдущий, но немного лучше: надо скачать **node js**. Установка в несколько пунктов(загуглите). Запустить **localhost**. Тут уже никаких путей к файлу указывать не надо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**3)** Установить расширение **code runner**, выделить код в файле и нажать *ctrl + alt + n*. У меня этот способ почему-то не работает...

Answer (score 0):

Прежде чем запускать код, нужно сконфигурировать `tasks.json` и объяснить среде, каким образом вы собираетесь его запускать. Подробная инструкция есть на [сайте](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) vscode.