# не работает JS в Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

Выдает такое при написании простой команды console.log('hello'). Сегодня только захотел начать изучать язык, помогите пожалуйста)

[Running] node "c:\JS\Untitled-1.js"
"node" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.118 seconds

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1001464/191482  оно?   также ещё может полезно будет https://qna.habr.com/q/502270

Comment: Советую пользоваться Webstorm

Comment: Nodejs установите, у Вас его нет